# PHP - Keeps Displaying phpinfo() Page

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, webserver, web-development-server

I'm using IIS 7, I Installed PHP 7.1 My PHP File :

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Saved It As "index.php" But whenever I run this it shows the phpinfo() page even while the file is completely empty...

Comment: Is there any `index.html` file at the root directory?

Comment: Yes There Is...

Comment: rename the page `index.html` to `old_index.html` and check once again.

Comment: Nops! Still Not Wokring.. But I Noticed One Thing... It Displays info Page Only When I Type http://localhost/index.php to Firefox URL box, if I open php file direct from location It displays a blank white page... :/

Answer (score 0):

1. check the default welcome page, .2 check your mapping  to www root path.

Comment: and how to do that? :/

Comment: you are not a baby, who just wait to be feed, right? so, google it!

Answer (score 0):

From official site:

> From the IIS Manager, click on the hostname of your server in the
>   Connections panel on the left.
>
> Double-click on the Handler Mappings icon.
>
> From the Handler Mappings Actions panel, click on Add Module Mapping.

Please follow the original [iis tutorial](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)